# Msbuild create apppool in specific framework version

Tags: msbuild-4.0

In my Msbuild project script, I want to set the apppool framework version as 4.0 while creating. What parameter should I add to the node:
 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a property that does the job. Hence, I set the default framework version in the IIS to 4.0 to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set the .Net version on the AppPool, you set it on the website.

You can do that with the `ASPNETVersion` value on the main setup property page.